# Comparing a 32 bit file size to 16 bit user input?

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm

I'm writing an assembler program, which analyzes files and outputs their information ( name and size ) to the file. I'm basically using 4Eh and 4Eh interrupts to search for files : they both return DTA object with according information about that file in it.

It returns a 32-bit filesize which I have to compare with a 16-bit user inputted size (I have to only output files information if it's larger than the given - user inputted - size).

The obvious problem here is that I don't know how to convert a 32 bit number into a 16 bit number, because otherwise I can't compare them. Maybe someone knows how to perform this conversion or has any other ideas on how to implement this comparison ?

If possible, maybe someone could provide an example code in TASM Intel x86 assembly

Comment: Obviously if the top 16 bits of the file size are non-zero it is a bigger number than your user input. If they are zero, then you have two 16 bit numbers you can compare. Easy.

Comment: Values in range 0..65535 will fit into 16 bits (upper 16 bits will be zeroes). 65536+ values will have some non zero bit in upper 16 bits. If your app takes as input only 16 bit value (0..65535), then you can check first if the length is >= 65536 by checking upper 16 bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking about it backwards.

You want to zero-extend the 16-bit number to 32, and do a 32-bit comparison.  (In C, operations on different types promote to a type that's wide enough to hold them both, because that's almost always what you want.)

As Jester explains, this means the upper 16 of your user input is always zero, so doing the upper half of the extended-precision / BigInteger comparison is simply checking that the upper half of the file size for non-zero.  Then, if the file size is small enough that it might be below a 16-bit user input, compare the low half with the threshold.

---

You can also check for less-than with only one branch instruction by **doing an extended-precision subtract**:

```
file_loop:               ; do {
    load a new file size

    ;; file size in dx:ax,  threshold in cx
    cmp    ax, cx        ; low half (non-destructive: cmp = sub but without writing ax)
    sbb    dx, 0         ; high half. (destructive)
    ; ZF reflects only the high-half compare result
    ; CF is useful (and so are SF/OF for signed compare).
    ; Avoid JCC conditions that depend on ZF, like JA.
    jnb   file_loop    ; } while(CF==0);   (JNB = JNC)

;;; dx:ax < 0:cx unsigned was true.
;;; So we know the original DX was 0 (and is now 0xFFFF)
;;; AX = the file size (which we didn't destroy), and we know it fits in 16 bits.

    do something with this file
    jmp  file_loop
```

This is nice and compact, but probably not particularly better than `cmp/jz` and `cmp/jb`, especially if the 32-bit number is in memory.  (You don't want to use `sbb` with a memory destination; that's less efficient.)

---

Converting 32->16 is trivial: just truncate by ignoring the upper 16 bits.  But you seem to have already realized that wouldn't do what you want.

To answer your old title: to convert a 32-bit integer in dx:ax to a 16-bit integer in cx, use this instruction: `mov cx, ax`.

Comment: Does this mean, that in the same way, I can compare 8bit to 32bit numbers ? I mean if I divide 32bit number into 4 8bit numbers ( two high parts, two low parts ), I can therefore assume if any of the high parts or most left low part have any non-zero numbers in them, then the number is higher than any 8bit number. And otherwise, I can do the comparison between the right most low part of the 32bit number with the 8 bit number.

Comment: @JonasPetraška: Yes, but note that you can still check the upper 16 of the 32-bit number in one step, because 8086 is a 16-bit architecture.  You can also `movzx` (386) or `xor ax,ax` / `mov al, single_byte` to zero-extend your 8-bit number to 16, and then you can do a 16-bit compare for the low half of the 32-bit number.

Comment: @PeterCorder : Thanks very much !

Comment: @JonasPetraška also keep in mind (when checking separate bytes in memory) x86 is little endian, so the file size in DTA is very likely too in LE, i.e. size 66051 is in memory stored as 4 bytes `03 02 01 00`, so the lowest 8 bits are at offset +0, highest 8 bits are at +3 address. ... i.e. to check upper 16b for zero from memory: `xor ax,ax` `cmp [dta_fsize+2],ax` `jnz size_above_65535` `mov ax,[dta_fsize] ; = lower 16 bits (value 0..65535)`.

Comment: Also related: you can look at C compiler output (for 64-bit integers in 32-bit mode) to see what instructions it uses.  https://godbolt.org/z/crPYb3Kf8.  For other comparisons like `==`, just change the C source.